# How can I use a generic type's type argument as the type of a method parameter?

Tags: c#, generics

There are 1 base-class and 2 sub-class:

```cs
class A<T> { }
class B : A<int> { }
class C : A<string> { }
```

I want use the method `test` like this:

```cs
void test<T>(? param)
{
    // Do something, need to use param, no returns
}
void main()
{
    test<B>(1);        // ok!
    test<B>("1");      // Error!

    test<C>("1");      // ok!
    test<C>(1);        // Error!
}
```

I want to write only one generic type `T` (which in this case: B or C), then I get generic type parameters to limit `param` (which in this case: int or string).

The key is to limit `param` according to `T`.

How do I write the method `test`?

PS: A more specific example:

```
namespace T
{
    abstract class A<T>
    {
        public abstract void OnCreate(T param);
    }
    class B : A<int>
    {
        public override void OnCreate(int score)
        {
            int r = score + 1;
            Console.WriteLine(r);
        }
    }
    class C : A<string>
    {
        public override void OnCreate(string msg)
        {
            string r = $"msg:{msg}";
            Console.WriteLine(r);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {

        static void Main()
        {
            // already initialized elsewhere
            var b = new B();
            var c = new C();

            // Solution 1:
            b.OnCreate(1);
            c.OnCreate("this is a msg");

            // Solution 2:
            // I want to use method "run" to achieve solution 1, but I don't know how to write "run"
            run<B>(b, 1);
            run<C>(c, "this is a msg");
            // I want to limit param, if I write wrong type, then Error:
            run<B>(c, 1);       // Error!
            run<B>(b, "1");     // Error!    
            run<C>(c, 222);     // Error!
        }

        static void run<T>(T ins, ?? param) where ??
        {
            // Do Something
            Console.WriteLine("Use method run start");

            ins.OnCreate(param);

            // Do Something
            Console.WriteLine("Use method run end");
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, I want to use Solution-2 instead of Solution-1.

Comment: What does `test` do?

Comment: Would it be OK with `test<int, B>(1);` and `test<string, C>("a");`?

Comment: Depending on what `test` actually does with that parameter you may completely omit `B` and `C` and use `A<int>` or `A<string>` instead. You surely need some logic that is even able to deal with those types.

Comment: You just write `void test<T>(? param) where T : A<?>` and then the question mark will be a placeholder for the same type which is not declared anywhere. No, that was a joke. You have to promote your `?` to a second generic parameter, as in my first comment (or Olivier Rogier's answer below). Or you can use the strategy in Marcel Hoekstra's answer instead.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yes! I can use a second generic parameter to finish it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
static void test<TInstance, TParam>(TParam param)
where TInstance : A<TParam>
{
}

test<B, int>(1);
test<C, string>("1");
```

You must specify two generic parameters because one is for the type and one is for the parameter that is the same of the generic parameter of the type.

There is no way yet to infer TParam from TInstance, as I know, unless using reflexion...

If you want to restrict T and TParam you can add some constraints like these:

```
class A<T> 
where T : IComparable, IConvertible
{ 
}

static void test<TInstance, TParam>(TParam param)
where TInstance : A<TParam>
where TParam : IComparable, IConvertible
{
}
```

Hence it only allows numbers and strings as well as any type that implements these interfaces.

Comment: Thanks, I use two generic parameters to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do write the method in the A class:

```
public static void Main()
{
    new B().test(1);
    new C().test("1");
}


abstract class A<T> {
   public void test(T value){
       Console.WriteLine(value);
   }
}
class B : A<int> {  }
class C : A<string> { }
```

Comment: This might be the solution, although I'm hesitant to upvote since we don't know what OP is trying to achieve.

Comment: thanks, it's a solution. But in my real project, It's better not to instantiate B or C in `Main()` because it's already instantiated elsewhere.

Comment: @fengyong explain what you want to do. That `Do Something` is the most important part of the question

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I want to limit `param` according to `T` in the method `test`.

Comment: @fengyong that doesn't explain anything. It doesn't say anything about `Do Something`. Yes, you want to use that type. Why? To create an instance using the value? To compare with another value? To write a unit test? Using `T` inside the parent class allows things that aren't possible in a unit test method. `Do Something` matters

Comment: @fengyong You can just add `static` to Marcel's method above, then in `Main` it becomes just `B.test(1)` and `C.test("1")`. __Addition:__ Of course, the notation `B.test(1)` in that case is really a strange way to write `A<int>.test(1)`, but the C# compiler allows it, and sometimes it can save a low of space in the code.